# WinJS How to select a listview item on page load

Tags: windows-8, winjs

I'm trying to select the first item in my listview control as soon as my nav page loads. The following code does not seem to have an effect. If i put the "selection.set(0)" code inside of a button click handler it will work fine, but it will not work as soon as the page loads which is my desired effect. Anyone have any ideas? I must be missing something very basic here!

**HTML**

```
<div id="basicListView"
 data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
 data-win-options="{itemDataSource : ex.itemList.dataSource,
 itemTemplate: select('#mediumListIconTextTemplate'),
 layout : {type: WinJS.UI.ListLayout},
 selectionMode: 'single',
 tapBehavior: 'directSelect'
     }">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
    (function () {
        "use strict";
        var _lv = null;

        WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/page2/page2.html", {
            // This function is called whenever a user navigates to this page. It
            // populates the page elements with the app's data.
            ready: function (element, options) {
                // TODO: Initialize the page here.
                _lv = document.getElementById("basicListView").winControl;

                // This should select the first item in the listview though it seems to have no effect.
                _lv.selection.set(0);
            },
        });
    })();
```

Comment: where is ex.itemList.dataSource getting set? do you see the list getting populated? if yes - try using [loadingstatechanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700713.aspx) event and in the event handler set the item

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that the list is not populated when you try to access it.
Try to put this code in your ready event so you will know when the list is ready:

```
ready: function (element, options) {

var listView = element.querySelector(".itemslist").winControl;
listView .onloadingstatechanged = function (args) {
    if (args.srcElement === listView .element && listView .loadingState === "complete") {

       //and here you set your item
       _lv = document.getElementById("basicListView").winControl;
       _lv.selection.set(0);

    }
};
}
```